# Trouble making a simple, number guessing game

Tags: python, python-2.7

My code :

```
from random import randint

def main():
    print "Guess a number between 1 and 100"
    randomNumber = 35
    found = False

    while not found:
        userGuess = raw_input("Your guess:")
        if userGuess == randomNumber:
            print "You got it"
        elif userGuess > randomNumber:
            print"Guess lower!"
        else:
            print "Guess higher"

main()
```

When I start the script and start writing in random numbes I always get "Guess lower" So I tried doing it a little bit differently. I made this code :

```
print "Guess a number between 0 and 100"

random = "36"
numb = raw_input("Enter your guess: ")

while numb != random:
    numb = raw_input()  
    if numb < random:
        print "Guess lower"
    if numb > random:
        print "Guess higher"

if numb == random:
    print " You guessed it"
    exit()
```

Can you help me finding what's wrong?

Comment: The exit condition's placed outside the loop in the second code, so you'll never be able to guess correctly. Then, this is a number guessing game, but you're dealing with _strings_, not numbers, for some reason. After that, in the second code, you should swap the `print` statements as one should try a greater number when their guess is lower than the target and vice versa. All in all, you should probably read more theory about types in Python and especially converting from strings to numbers.

Comment: The first example will work if you add `break` after `print "You got it`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are comparing a number to a string from the users input. Use the following line to convert the input to a number.

```
numb = int(raw_input("Enter your guess: "))
```

You also need to set `found` to `true` inside the first if-condition so that the loop is exited once the number is guessed.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

`raw_input()` returns a string. You need to cast it to `int`, and then work with it.

```
x = int(raw_input())
```

As for second example you are to compare strings with strings, which would be compared lexicographically, and that's not what you want.